# Sections invisible until window resize

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I cant get sections to work properly, they are invisible until a window resize.

foundation.css:2413 code at this line setting section-container to visibility:hidden
I copied the actual code but even examples doesnt work in that containing divs.

```
<div class="large-8 columns large-centered">                        
    <form class="custom ajaxform" data-validate="parsley" method="post" action="formProcess"> 
        <input type="hidden" name="formtype" value="test" >               
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Test</legend>
            <span class="icon24 icon-close"></span>
            <h4><small>Test</small></h4>
            <?= View::make('forms.header') ?> 
            <h4><small>Test</small></h4>
            <div class="section-container tabs" data-section="tabs">
                <section class="active">
                    <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#">Test</a></p>
                    <div class="content" data-section-content>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="large-4 columns">
                                <label>Test *</label>
                                <input type="text" name="test" data-required="true">
                            </div>                                                                                               
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
                <section>
                    <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#">test Tab 2</a></p>
                    <div class="content" data-section-content>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="large-6 columns">
                                <label>Second *</label>
                                <input type="text" name="second" data-required="true">
                            </div>                                                        
                        </div>                                                        
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>                
            <div class="row">
                <div class="large-12 columns">
                    <button class="small radius button" style="float:right" type="submit">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>      
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because you were adding the sections programmatically. In that case, you need to force a resize, so that foundation will be triggered to draw them correctly.

I had the same problem, and after quick googling, this would solve it:

```
$('[data-section]').trigger('resize');
```

Answer (score 0):

If a 
`<div>`
 is not visible then it may means that it doesn't have a well defines height and width. Then rendering a content is not meaningful. To avoid that flaw we have to add a height and width.

`<div class="section-container tabs" data-section="tabs" style="height: 400px; width : 400px;"></div>`

Mention your respective height and width.